# baseHref not working for assets - Angular 14

Tags: angular, nginx, assets

We are trying to deploy an Angular app on an Nginx server on ubuntu 20.

The application is working well and the baseHref property mentionned in angular.json file seems to work fine, the JS files are correctly loaded. The angular.json is :

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "baseHref": "/users/",
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          }
```

The url is like https://url/users

So the "/users/" baseHref is correcly set.

The problem is that baseHref is not used for assets. Images are not loaded as SVG icons and all stuff inside the assets folder.

Is there a solution for that in Angular or do we have to hardly write prefixes with environment variables maybe?

We tried to remove baseHref and the application is not displayed anymore because JS files are not loaded. That shows the parameter is correctly took in account.